# How to do X12 EDI mapping XML to XSD in visual studio without using Biztalk server dev

Tags: mapping, azure-logic-apps, edi, x12

I am trying to create map file(.XSLT) for Azure logic apps integration account. I am not able create mapping from visual studio since I don't have Biztalk server. How to do X12 EDI mapping XML to XSD in visual studio without using Biztalk server dev

Comment: Currently following up with microsoft on the same Q. BT Dev Edition is now limited to visual studio enterprise subscriptions. Options seem to be (1) develop on the server via remote desktop, (2) get VS enterprise. Meeting w/CDW and MS next week, crossing fingers.

Comment: EDI is structured text.  You'd need to write a parser to split the EDI into XML tags.  That's basically what BizTalk and other EDI translators do.